# Dragging multiple images to iOS Simulator broken in Xcode 7.x ? (7.2)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

In a recent Xcode (6.4?) they enabled the ability to drag multiple images to the simulator window and have them added to the photos app.

(Previous to this, a single dragged image would open in safari, from which you could save it.)

Recently, either in Xcode 7, or I suspect after Xcode 7, I noticed that this functionality is broken.  When I drag multiple images to the simulator, it just freezes up, and I have to force quit it.

My current version of Xcode is 7.2.  The simulator I'm dragging to is iPhone6 8.4 and iPhone6 9.2.

Does anyone else see this problem/have a solution?

Comment: it’s working for me - Xcode 7.2...

Comment: you can drag multiple images at the same time?  one works fine for me, but not multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incompatibility with BetterTouchTool.  Quitting BetterTouchTool is not sufficient.  BetterTouchTool's accessibility privileges must also be revoked in Security & Privacy.

Upgrading to BetterTouchTool 1.5.2, whose version notes allude to fixing a simulator problem, does not appear to have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dragging multiple images (and now also videos) into the simulator window should be working fine.   They should all get added to the camera roll.  This is working fine for me, and there are no other reports of problems.  I suggest you try using the simctl command line to try adding your photos as maybe one (or more) of them are problematic, and that might produce more helpful diagnostics if something is wrong with them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  There's nothing wrong with them.  They work fine one at a time, and they are the same images i've been dragging to the simulator for years now.  :)

Comment: BTW: simctl addphoto <device guid from simctl list> photo1Path photo2Path ... does work fine, in case someone else runs into this and needs a work around.  I think the problem is in the enumeration of drop items in the simulator drag handler.  Not sure why it would only effect me though.

Comment: Try downloading older simulator runtimes from Xcode's Preferences.  Do you have issues with older runtimes, or is it just newer iOS runtimes that are problematic?  I want to understand if the issue here is on the iOS side of the tools side.

Comment: Before I posted, i tried quitting all apps i have running that I thought might be affecting global event actions, namely Spectacle and BetterTouchTool.  However, after looking at your post history, and seeing some issues with the Simulator and BetterTouchTool, I actually revoked BetterTouchTool Accessibility privileges, and the issue no longer reproduced.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you please test the Xcode 7.3 beta as well?  The accessibility interaction issue was fixed in 7.3, so I'm hoping that it still works for you in 7.3 with BetterTouchTool re-enabled.